# How to format a date in Ruby on Rails with alternative date format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a legacy database where each user's preferred `date_format` can have one of the following values:

```
dd.mm.yy
dd/mm/yy
mm/dd/yy
```

I noticed that this format plays nicely with some of the javascript functions (which is probably why they've chosen it).

But how can these formats be used to format a date in Ruby on Rails?

I would like to use something like `date.strftime("dd.mm.yy")` but `strftime` won't accept any of the three formats above.

How can this be done?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Time.html#method-i-strftime

Comment: because this not valid format string options `date.strftime("dd.mm.yy")` you should use `date.strftime("%d.%m.%y")` or `date.strftime("%d/%m/%y")` or `date.strftime("%m/%d/%y")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you question properly you just have to modify the format string so that it can be recognized by `strftime`. For example, using [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-gsub):

```
def my_date_format(date, format)
  strftime_format = format.gsub(/([dmy])\1/, 'dd' => '%d', 'mm' => '%m', 'yy' => '%Y')
  date.strftime(strftime_format)
end

require 'date'
my_date_format(Date.today, 'dd.mm.yy')
# => "01.08.2014"
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not accepting it, because the `dd.mm.yy` is not a strftime format. The correct pattern for that is `"%d.%m.%y"`, `"%d/%m/%y"` and `"%m/%d/%y"`

```
Date.today.strftime("%d.%m.%y") #=> "01.08.14"
Date.today.strftime("%d/%m/%y") #=> "01/08/14"
Date.today.strftime("%m/%d/%y") #=> "08/01/14"
```

So you need to simply convert your patterns, for example "dd.mm.yy":

```
"dd.mm.yy".gsub('dd','%d').gsub('mm', '%m').gsub('yy', '%y') #=> "%d.%m.%y"
```

And you can use it in `strftime`:

```
Date.today.strftime("dd.mm.yy".gsub('dd','%d').gsub('mm', '%m').gsub('yy', '%y')) #=> "01.08.14"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime

You need to use `%d` etc.